# Перенос .py файлов на Google Cloud

Tags: python, ubuntu, google-cloud

Сразу говорю, компьютером владею плохо, посему вопрос может показаться глупым, но все же, как перенести готовый .py файл на vm в Google Cloud и соответственно запустить его там

Comment: `rsync`, `scp`?

Comment: Да, спасибо, уже разобрался

Comment: Тогда напиши в ответе как ты это сделал.

Answer (score 0):

Решил проблему через создание на vm нового файла и переноса туда кода через копирование и вставку. А потом ещё посоветовали pscp